# How to optimize For Loops in R? I am aware of the apply function but currently facing problem in applying it

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

So basically I have a vector of tags that I want to find in my Transcript column (row by row) and if I find any word from the tags in my Transcript string, I want to create a separate column concatenating all the tags as shown in the example below (see image):

```
tags=c("loan","deposit","quarter","morning")
```

So, the output should look like this:

[Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFTjj.jpg)

Currently, I am able to **tag this by using two for loops** i.e. one to go over Tags vector and the other to go over my data frame's Transcript column one-by-one. But, I have a tag list of around 500 words and data frame has more than 100,000 rows. So, I am concerned about the run time. Is there any better way to optimize my R code using **apply function** or any other method?

Using, the following code to tag all the rows of Transcript column one-by-one

```
for (i in 1:length(tags)) {
    
    for (j in 1:nrow(FinalData)){
      check_tag <- str_extract(string = FinalData$Cleaned_Transcript[j], pattern = tags[i])
      
      if (is.na(check_tag)==FALSE) {
        FinalData$Tags[j] <- stri_remove_empty(paste(FinalData$Tags[j],check_tag,sep = ","))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are open to not using a for loop, but if so, here's a tidyverse approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(Transcript = c("This is example text a", "this is loan", "deposit is not quarter"))

# as per comment from TO, we want to provide an input vector of tags
my_tags <- c("loan", "deposit", "quarter", "morning")
my_tags_collapsed <- str_c(my_tags, collapse = "|")

# We can now use the collapsed tags in the str_extract_all function
dat %>%
  mutate(test = str_extract_all(Transcript, my_patterns_collapsed)) %>%
  unnest_wider(test) %>%
  mutate(across(-Transcript, replace_na, "")) %>%
  mutate(Tags_Marked = apply(across(-Transcript), 1, str_c, collapse = ",")) %>%
  select(Transcript, Tags_Marked)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Transcript             Tags_Marked    
  <chr>                  <chr>          
1 This is example text a ,              
2 this is loan           loan,          
3 deposit is not quarter deposit,quarter
```

Admittedly, this is not 100% ok, since you still get the comma separator for 0-length characters.

Alternative could be to not concatenate the strings into one column, but keep them as separate columns which would mean that you could stop much earlier:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(test = str_extract_all(Transcript, my_tags_collapsed)) %>%
  unnest_wider(test)
```

which would give you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Transcript             ...1    ...2   
  <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>  
1 This is example text a NA      NA     
2 this is loan           loan    NA     
3 deposit is not quarter deposit quarter
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what if, I have a vector for tags let's say TAGS that contains 500 words that I need to search for. TAGS=c("xyz","abc","pqr"). Should i pass "TAGS" directly in this code line: mutate(test = str_extract_all(Transcript, TAGS))?

Comment: We can use an input vector, but we need to concatenate it first. I'll update my post.

Comment: Note: I editted my solution to make it considerably faster when using large data sets, i.e. getting rid of tidyverse's `rowwise` functions and using `apply` instead.

Comment: my_patterns_c should be my_tags_collapsed? Am i right?

Comment: Correct, sorry about that typo.

Comment: In this code, if let's say "morning" appears thrice in my Transcript then Tags_Marked will have morning 3 times I guess.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.